# Suggestion command, struggles in adding reactions to the message that was sent

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello I need help in making a discord.py command. I made the first part but now I need it to make the second part which is adding reactions to the message that got sent.

Here's my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, suggestion):
    suggestion_channel = client.get_channel(837705185316438037)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Suggestion by {ctx.author.mention}", description=f"{suggestion}")
    embed.set_footer("Oxfordshire Administration ")
    await suggestion_channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("Sent")
```

Comment: Have you attempted in figuring out how to add a reaction?

Comment: yes but idk how to specify what message to react on

Comment: Ok, you should've specified that in the question.,

Comment: aight sorry ill edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a reaction to a message you need a [Message object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message) to add the reactions to.

`suggestion_channel.send(embed=embed)` returns a `Message` object for you. If you assign that to a variable you can then call `.add_reaction(<reaction>)` on it.

For specifics on how to add a reaction see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message

Comment: how do i specify what message to add reactions in

Comment: The Message obj is the message that denotes which one to add a reaction to. ``x = ctx.send()`` then ``x.add_reaction``

Comment: @aleissues When you send a message via `.send()`, a Message object is returned. Just store it in a variable.

Comment: so in my case `await suggestion_channel.add_reaction(<reaction>)`

Comment: No, you cannot add a reaction to a channel.

Comment: oh so i should do `x = await suggestion_channel.send....` and then `x.add_reaction`